# How to position my clouds images in css away from each other?

Tags: css, css-animations

Hey guys I'm stuck right now with my clouds in the same position. I have one cloud where it's supposed to be but the other cloud is not where it's supposed to be and I can't get it to a position on the webpage where I want it. Instead of it right over my other cloud. I want the small cloud to be on the right side of the page. Can anyone please help me?

[image: These are my clouds]

CSS

```
  @charset "utf-8";
  /* CSS Document */


  /*This is for the fresh farms and clouds image*/
  body
  {
  background-image: url("Image/cloud.png"),url("Image/cloud.png"), 
  url("Image/FreshFarmsBG.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 10%,20%, cover;
  background-position: top right, top left, cover;

    height: auto;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background position values should have a hyphen between each value so it would be

```
background-position: top-right, top-left, cover;
```

EDIT:
What you can do is set the background to 1 image only
so it would be

```
background-image:url("Image/FreshFarmsBG.jpg");
```

then in the .html file you can add 2 new elements using the img tag, and use the

```
float: left
```

attribute on the first image, and..

```
float: right
```

on the second image in the css file, don't forget to give each image a separate class so you can define each one separately. For example:

```
img .cloud1{
  float: left
}

img .cloud1{
  float: right
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just fixed that but It did nothing to change the clouds positioning.

Comment: What img tag did you use?

Comment: You can use the img tag inside the body tag in your .html file like so
```
<body>
<div class="">
<img src="Image/cloud.png" class="cloud1" alt="cloudimg">
<img src="Image/cloud.png" class="cloud2" alt="cloudimg">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ah thanks! It worked!